# Use string.Replace to match whole words

Tags: c#, string, replace, .net-2.0

I'm using NET 2.0 and WinForms.

Currently, I need a code to replace a string with another one in a given text, but in the text it should only look for whole words. What I mean is:

```
string name = @"COUNTER = $40
CLOCK_COUNTER = $60";
name = name.Replace("COUNTER", "COUNT");
```

It should only replace the first instance of `COUNTER` with `COUNT`, because that's whole word. However, it seems `string.Replace` does not take whole word into consideration.

Please don't recommend regex. I have already tried it, and it's too slow for my needs. I need something very fast and efficient. How could I accomplish this?

Comment: Sorry bud, it's regex or nothing.

Comment: "Please don't recommend regex." What exactly is the circumstances where regex is to slow but string.Replace is acceptable?  You do understand how string.Replace does it magic, and the memory usage it implies right?

Comment: @codesparkle -- CLOCK_COUNTER has a space after it, but another prefix. So I think a "word" is defined as "newline before and space after it" ..

Comment: @asawyer: Many people have already told me Regex.Replace is slower, and I can even give examples to prove it. In one of my codes it was almost 1 second slower compared to string.Replace in a large file. But that's besides the point.

Comment: I deleted my original comment because it was obviously not helping us get anywhere. Is @Matten's definition right? o.O

Comment: @david, isn't that exactly what codesparkle says. That a word is something that has space before and after.

Comment: "I need something very fast and efficient." That is Regex, certainly not string.Replace. Why would you NOT want to use regular expressions in this instance? What patterns have you tried and how did you measure the performances?

Comment: @codesparkle: Yeah, he's right. Sorry about my previous comment. I deleted it. However, there can be whitespace before instead of new line as well.

Comment: @david I guess my question is then, is that 1 second extra execution time worth the extra complexity involved in rolling out your own custom version of /\b(word)\b/ ?  We need to to know the context of the performance problem. Are you doing this on the inside of a tight loop? Is is a one off batch file processor? How fast is "fast enough" ? How slow is "To slow" ?

Comment: Note that some languages like Japanese and Thai do not put spaces between words.

Answer (score 8):

```
string input = @"COUNTER = $40
CLOCK_COUNTER = $60";

string name = Regex.Replace(input, @"\bCOUNTER\b", "COUNT");
```

`\b` marks word boundries.

---

The only alternative to Regex is to develop your own algorithm! Search for "COUNTER" and test the previous and following character for not being a word character.

---

**EDIT**:

Here is my solution as extension method:

```
public static class ReplaceWordNoRegex
{
    private static bool IsWordChar(char c)
    {
        return Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) || c == '_';
    }

    public static string ReplaceFullWords(this string s, string oldWord, string newWord)
    {
        if (s == null) {
            return null;
        }
        int startIndex = 0;
        while (true) {
            int position = s.IndexOf(oldWord, startIndex);
            if (position == -1) {
                return s;
            }
            int indexAfter = position + oldWord.Length;
            if ((position == 0 || !IsWordChar(s[position - 1])) && (indexAfter == s.Length || !IsWordChar(s[indexAfter]))) {
                s = s.Substring(0, position) + newWord + s.Substring(indexAfter);
                startIndex = position + newWord.Length;
            } else {
                startIndex = position + oldWord.Length;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT #2:**
And here is a solution with StringBuilder.

```
public static string ReplaceFullWords(this string s, string oldWord, string newWord)
{
    if (s == null) {
        return null;
    }
    int startIndex = 0; // Where we start to search in s.
    int copyPos = 0; // Where we start to copy from s to sb.
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (true) {
        int position = s.IndexOf(oldWord, startIndex);
        if (position == -1) {
            if (copyPos == 0) {
                return s;
            }
            if (s.Length > copyPos) { // Copy last chunk.
                sb.Append(s.Substring(copyPos, s.Length - copyPos));
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
        int indexAfter = position + oldWord.Length;
        if ((position == 0 || !IsWordChar(s[position - 1])) && (indexAfter == s.Length || !IsWordChar(s[indexAfter]))) {
            sb.Append(s.Substring(copyPos, position - copyPos)).Append(newWord);
            copyPos = position + oldWord.Length;
        }
        startIndex = position + oldWord.Length;
    }
}
```

Comment: Although that's what he should do, it does go directly against what he asked for (no regex).

Comment: As the reason he doesn't want to use is regex is for speed, and assuming he's dealing with large several thousand character strings and multiple replacements, you probably should use a stringbuilder preallocated to the length of the input string here. If you're going to roll your own algorithm, makes sense to do it efficiently.

Comment: StringBuilder has no `IndexOf()`, which means that you have to work on the original string to find positions and on StringBuilder to construct a new string. Not very obvious.

Comment: Nevertheless, I added a StringBuilder version. It is a bit more difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Small workaround:

```
string name = @"COUNTER = $40
CLOCK_COUNTER = $60";
name=" "+name;
name = name.Replace(" COUNTER ", " COUNT ");
```

Main idea that you have to mark the word you're going to replace with some sort of symbols that other words that you do not want to replace have not

Comment: Suggest something other without regex!

Comment: this doesn't replace COUNTER because it doesn't have a space in front? did you mean `name = " " + name;`?

Comment: @elastep " in a given text ". This solution is specific to the given example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot achieve that string replace any faster (I'm talking about developing time) than by RegExp

```
        string input = @"COUNTER = $40 CLOCK_COUNTER = $60";
        string pattern = @"\bCOUNTER\b";
        string replacement = "COUNT";
        var regex = new Regex(pattern,RegexOptions.Compiled);
        string result = regex.Replace(input, replacement);
```

Adding RegexOptions.Compiled makes it faster if you intend to reuse

-------------------UPDATE-----------------------------

i remembered about this article that may fit your needs:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/fastestcscaseinsstringrep.aspx

Comment: That's not true, technically if you rolled your old string replace algorithm, pre allocating a new stringbuilder to the correct size, I'm sure you could make it a lot faster. The point is it's almost certainly not worth it.

Comment: yes, i agree. The "any faster" i was talking about imply developping time